# Do I include Javadoc in Netbeans Zipped or Unzipped?

Tags: google-chrome, javadoc, netbeans-7, osx-mountain-lion

In `Netbeans | Tools | Java Platforms`, I included the `javafx-apidocs` as **zip** file.

then I wanted to check the javadoc in `Google Chrome`. I opened the link from within `Netbeans`. The URL looks like this :

**http**//**127.0.0.1**:8082/resource/**jar:file**:/Library/Java/JavaApiDocs/javafx-apidocs **.zip!/api**/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.**html**

But the view on `Google Chrome` is not good, or well organized. Do I have to unzip it and then include it on `Netbeans` please ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unzipped allows me to view the *Javadoc* correctly on the Browser.